# NoMethodError in Posts#show error in section 6.4 of RailsGuides

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methodnotfound

I am trying to follow the RailsGuides, http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

Now, in section 6.4 where I am supposed to be able to add comments in my blog site, I am encountering this error:

```
NoMethodError in Posts#show
Showing C:/Sites/blog/app/views/posts/show.html.erb where line #12 raised: </br>
undefined method `comments' for #<Post:0x3a99668
```

below is the snippet in my show.html.erb

```
<h2>Add a comment:</h2>
<%= form_for([@post, @post.comments.build]) do |f| %>
 <p>
   <%= f.label :commenter %><br>
   <%= f.text_field :commenter %>
```

Below is the snippet for my comments controller:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController  
  def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.create(comment_params)
    redirect_to post_path(@post)
  end

  private
    def comment_params
      params.require(:comment).permit(:commenter, :body)
    end
end
```

Below is my Posts controller:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
def new
     @post = Post.new
end

def create
    @post = Post.new(params[:post].permit(:title, :text))

    if @post.save
        redirect_to @post
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end

def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end

def index
    @posts = Post.all
end

def edit
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end

def update
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])

    if @post.update(params[:post].permit(:title, :text))
        redirect_to @post
    else
        render 'edit'
    end
 end

 def destroy
      @post = Post.find(params[:id])
      @post.destroy

      redirect_to posts_path
     end

private
  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :text)
  end
end
```

Please help me thanks.

-aguds

Comment: Make sure you have correctly followed section 6.2 of the same guide.

Comment: Yes I did.. In fact I already tried copy pasting the code snippets from the site itself.

Comment: Can i see your app/modelss/post.rb file? And meanwhile did you try restarting your server in case you are running in production mode.

Comment: I tried to restart my server and the code is now working.. I do not what happened. Thanks for the help

Comment: I do not gave enough reputation points to vote for the answer. But will do

Comment: You can still accept by checking the right mark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's saying

"**line #12** raised:
**undefined method `comments'** for #< Post:0x3a99668 >"

That means in line 12 of your show.html.erb you are calling **comments** method on an object of Post, but that method is not defined.

So you need to check in your Post class that following relation is there.

app/models/post.rb

```
has_many :comments
```

The server needs to restarted  once you add a new Model. (You added Comment.)

The general rule of thumb here is making changes to anything outside of app/ or config/routes.rb will require a restart.

Refer: [When do I need to restart server in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17729345/when-do-i-need-to-restart-server-in-rails)

Comment: I have added the has_many in post.rb already. But still I encounter the same error. I will edit my question to include other code snippets