# couldn't find file 'bootstrap' with type 'application/javascript'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am watching the old One Month Ruby on Rails lectures without being enrolled in the course and encountered this problem. I have searched through about 20 stackoverflow and github tutorials and can't find the problem, any help is greatly appreciated. (This is my first time posting here so if I am doing something wrong or need to include more information let me know).

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.2.6'
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
group :production do
    gem 'pg'
end

group :development, :test do
    gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :assets do    
    gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
    gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
    gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.6'
    gem 'sass-rails', '>= 3.2'
end
```

Styles.css.scss :

```
@import "bootstrap";
```

application.js :

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap
//= require_tree .
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17729345/when-do-i-need-to-restart-server-in-rails) its clearly stated that you need to restart your server whenever a gem is installed or updated, if you upgrade ruby, or if you change some logic that runs during boot time (like `config/boot.rb` or `config/database.yml`). Otherwise it's generally ok not to, even if you edit/add models/controllers.

Answer (score 2):

Remove group "assets" from Gemfile. It is obsolete in Rails 4.

> Rails 4.0 removed the assets group from Gemfile. You'd need to remove
>   that line from your Gemfile when upgrading.

See [Ruby on Rails Guides](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#upgrading-from-rails-3-2-to-rails-4-0-gemfile)

Answer (score 1):

you use `gem bootstrap-sass` than in your application.js use

```
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
```

and in your application.css use

```
// "bootstrap-sprockets" must be imported before "bootstrap" and "bootstrap/variables"
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```